# AngularJS directive watch parent height change

Tags: css, angularjs

I am new to angular and was wondering if I could add a directive to a target div that listens to a parent div's height/width like an onchange event on javascript and adjust the target div's height/width accordingly...

I have looked into $scope.watch and suspect that this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes you can have a parent directive that will watch height/width change.
- and then, from, the child directive require the controller of the parent directive and and watch it.

Html :

```
<element-parent  height-width>
   <child-element-directive></child-element-directive>
<element-parent>
```

JS :

```
 app.directive('heighWidth', function(){

   return {
      scope: {
      },
      controller:function($scope){
         // .......... define setHeight and setWidth
         this.getHeightAndWidth = function(){
           // .......
         }
      },
      link : function(scope, elem, attrs){
          scope.$watch(function(){
             return {height: elem.height(), width: elem.width() };
          }, function(){
             ctrl.setHeight(elem.height());
             ctrl.setWidth(elem.width());
          } , true); // to compare the object value.
      }
   }


})



app.directive('childElementDirective', function(){

   return {
       require: 'heightWidth',
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
          scope.$watch(
             function(){ 
                 return ctrl.getHeightAndWidth();
             },
             function(heightAndWidth){
                 // ........   
             }, 
             true
          )
       }
   }

})
```